# NSTextView - Unable to edit text

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am creating a few NSTextView objects in an app for OSX using code like this:

```
NSTextView *testTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 700, 1200, 100)];
[testTextView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18]];
[testTextView setDelegate:self];
[testTextView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
[testTextView setString:@"Some text to populate this lovely NSTextView. I would like to be able to edit this text but I can't."];
[testTextView setEditable:TRUE];
[[self.window contentView] addSubview:testTextView];
[self.window makeFirstResponder:testTextView];
```

The NSTextView is displayed on screen correctly and the text is visible but I am unable to edit the text.

Can anyone point me as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks a lot

Ben

Comment: The exact same code works perfectly for me.. Is there any other view you are adding on top of the text view? What have you implemented in your delegate methods?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the fact my window is borderless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using tittle-less window then objects unable to edit like NsTextField ,NsTextView.......

If you are using  title less window ,
that window must be able to become a key window,you need to create a subclass of NSWindow and override -canBecomeKeyWindow as follows:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: This may be the issue. I use [_window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask]; to make my window borderless. Although I have made a CustomNSWindow class with your suggestion in and the NSTextView still isn't editable. However if I remove the borderless setting they edit fine.

Comment: if u want tittle less window you can put canBecomeKeyWindow method in CustomNSWindow class .it may be healpfull

Comment: If I add canBecomeKeyWindow and call [myWindow becomeKeyWindow] I can now see the flashing cursor in my Text Views but still can't edit.

Comment: don't call [myWindow becomeKeyWindow] just return yes-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {

return YES;
}

Comment: I have tried that option and it isn't working. I may remove the borderless option on my window. I will make the window fullscreen instead. That fixes the issue.

Comment: if you are using border window it edit fine.in earlier i am using border less window i am facing same problem.i am using canBecomeKeyWindow method in CustomNSWindow class .i got the solution